# Aggregate Date and quantity in same table for given ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below schema and data, we need to find the cumulative AggreageQty,   StationaryWaitTimeTotal,    StationaryRowCount for each vehicle for the dates given and i want to find the number of stops for each date with multiple entries.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Consolidate](
    [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VehicleId] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [DepotVisitStartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DepotVisitEndTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [StationaryStartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [StationaryEndTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ActualQty] [bigint] NULL,
    [AggreageQty] [bigint] NULL,
    [StationaryWaitTimeTotal] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [StationaryRowCount] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (1, N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T17:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:55:32.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T08:15:23.0000000' AS DateTime2), 10)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (1, N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T17:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T09:22:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T09:45:59.0000000' AS DateTime2), 20)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (1, N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T17:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:25:36.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T02:35:37.0000000' AS DateTime2), 33)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (1, N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T17:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T15:15:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T15:25:21.0000000' AS DateTime2), 56)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (2, N'KA2       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:21:35.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T10:25:13.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:15:23.0000000' AS DateTime2), 72)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (2, N'KA2       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:21:35.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:11:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:45:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), 42)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (3, N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:32:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:21:35.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:13:13.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T08:05:01.0000000' AS DateTime2), 15)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (3, N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:32:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:21:35.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T09:43:12.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T10:05:42.0000000' AS DateTime2), 22)
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Consolidate] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DepotVisitStartTime], [DepotVisitEndTime], [StationaryStartTime], [StationaryEndTime], [ActualQty]) VALUES (3, N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T13:12:21.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T19:23:32.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T14:13:13.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T14:45:21.0000000' AS DateTime2), 34)
```

The expected result for the values are

```
AggreageQty StationaryWaitTimeTotal StationaryRowCount

119 02:02:47:000    4
119 02:02:47:000    4
119 02:02:47:000    4
119 02:02:47:000    4

114  01:24:10:000   2
114  01:24:10:000   2

37   01:14:18:000   2
37   01:14:18:000   2
34  00:32:08:000    1
```

I also have other columns which has to be added in the result Col1, Col2, Col3 in which are part of the [Table_Consolidate]

Comment: Want all the columns to be displayed as part of an stored procedure to insert values into my destination table with the result columns.. 

StationaryWaitTimeTotal is calculated as Datediff(ms, d.StationaryEndTime, d.StationaryStartTime)

Comment: Third row in the sample data generates negative Stationarytime. Correct value is: `StationaryEndTime =  2019-02-15 12:35:37.0000000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third  row in the sample data generates negative Stationarytime:

```
StationaryStartTime = 2019-02-15 11:25:36.0000000   
StationaryEndTime =  2019-02-15 02:35:37.0000000

-- the correct value is:
StationaryEndTime =  2019-02-15 12:35:37.0000000
```

After fixing sample data expected values can be retrieved via:

```
SELECT    

AggreageQty  = SUM(ActualQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Sno,   DepotVisitStartTime),

StationaryWaitTimeTotal  = CAST(DATEADD(SECOND,  SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StationaryStartTime, StationaryEndTime) ) OVER (PARTITION BY Sno,  DepotVisitStartTime), 0) AS TIME),

StationaryRowCount =  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Sno, DepotVisitStartTime)

FROM [dbo].[Table_Consolidate]
```

Results to:

```
AggreageQty StationaryWaitTimeTotal StationaryRowCount
119 02:02:47    4
119 02:02:47    4
119 02:02:47    4
119 02:02:47    4
114 01:24:10    2
114 01:24:10    2
37  01:14:18    2
37  01:14:18    2
34  00:32:08    1
```

Comment: Getting error on my realtime database table.

.Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: It was perhaps because `dateadd(ms...)`, adjusted to use seconds

Comment: can u guide me on the solution

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that, but perhaps some core things. The idea behind is to use **Window aggregations**. By using them you can change a context of the aggregation. This is a good introductory article: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Comment: Thanks for the link, Can you provide the alternative sql query to avoid the error which i get to adjust to use the seconds for 
StationaryWaitTimeTotal

Comment: I actually already adjusted :) in my answer, it has seconds instead of miliseconds and calculation simplified. Can you try that one?

Comment: Can you help me on the following column sql query 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831602/value-based-on-sequence-for-each-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(tc.ActualQty) OVER(PARTITION BY tc.Sno, tc.DepotVisitStartTime) AggreageQty   
, CAST(DATEADD(ms,  SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StationaryStartTime, StationaryEndTime) ) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Sno, tc.DepotVisitStartTime) * 1000, 0) AS TIME)  
        AS StationaryWaitTimeTotal  
, COUNT(tc.ActualQty) OVER(PARTITION BY tc.Sno, tc.DepotVisitStartTime) StationaryRowCount    
FROM dbo.Table_Consolidate tc
```

The OUTPUT:

```
AggreageQty            StationaryWaitTimeTotal  StationaryRowCount
119                        16:02:47.0000000             4
119                        16:02:47.0000000             4
119                        16:02:47.0000000             4
119                        16:02:47.0000000             4
114                        01:24:10.0000000             2
114                        01:24:10.0000000             2
37                         01:14:18.0000000             2
37                         01:14:18.0000000             2
34                         00:32:08.0000000             1
```

Comment: StationaryWaitTimeTotal  value is given in the result.. 02:02:47:000

Comment: I also want all the columns to be displayed as part of an stored procedure to insert values into my destination table

Comment: Also in the last Sno 3 we have to calculate based on each entry

Comment: Thanks, but still if you check for the Sno 3 we have to calculate based on each date for vehicle AP3 has 2 entries on the DepotVisitStartTime , i want to have 2 group by.. refer my answer for this.. 

StationeryWaitTimeTotal is fine

Comment: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: @Raj I double checked a code and see the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for getting cumulative aggregations along with other columns.

```
SELECT *
       ,SUM(ActualQty) OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleId) AS AggregateQty
       ,(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,StationaryStartTime,StationaryEndTime)) OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleId))/3600 AS StattionaryWaitTimeTotal 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleId ORDER BY Sno) AS StationaryRowCount
FROM [dbo].[Table_Consolidate]
```

Comment: Thanks, but still if you check for the Sno 3 we have to calculate based on each date for vehicle AP3 has 2 entries on the DepotVisitStartTime , i want to have 2 group by.. refer my answer for this