# value based on sequence for each detail

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Datawarehouse for my database

Find the V,T,C in sequence for a given detail group by Shipment_id order by TASK_SEQUENCE_NUMBER where the order of TASK_TYPE is V then T then C.

This value can be 0 if there is no values for V,T,C in sequence 
In case of V,T,C is more than once, we can sum the values and display

below is the table schema and data with the result expected which has to be incorporated in a stored procedure with more columns in the Task_Main Table.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_Detail](
    [Task_Sid] [int] NULL,      [Shipment_ID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TASK_SEQUENCE_No] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TASK_TYPE] [varchar](1) NULL,      [TASK_DURATION] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,      [LOCATION_CODE] [varchar](15) NULL,         [TaskStart] [bigint] NULL    ) ON [PRIMARY]


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_Header](
    [Task_Sno] [int] NULL,      [Shipment_ID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Vehicle_Id] [nchar](10) NULL,      [DepotVisitStartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,      [Time_V] [bigint] NULL,         [Time_T] [bigint] NULL,     [Time_C] [bigint] NULL     ) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT [dbo].[Task_Detail] ([Task_Sid], [Shipment_ID], [TASK_SEQUENCE_No], [TASK_TYPE], [TASK_DURATION], [LOCATION_CODE], [TaskStart]) VALUES
(1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'K', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC39', 20),
(2, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(7 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(21 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 21),
 (3, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(58 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC38', 58),
 (4, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(6 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), NULL, 10),
 (5, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(8 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 30),
 (6, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(11 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'RJC', 11),
(7, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(9 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019027', 19)
, (8, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(7 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(29 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 29)
, (9, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'K', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), NULL, 20)
, (10, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(0 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'302', 0)
, (11, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(12 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 19)
, (12, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(13 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'E', CAST(11 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 11)
, (13, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(32 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'', 32)
, (14, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'K', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 20)
, (15, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(0 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC57', 0)
, (16, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(8 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 19)
, (17, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(9 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019027', 10)
, (18, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(21 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC38', 21)
, (19, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(11 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 30)
, (20, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(21 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 21)
, (21, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC39', 19)
, (22, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'302', 10)
, (23, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(0 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'302', 0)
, (24, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(4 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(29 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 29)
, (25, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T', CAST(19 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'LC57', 19)
, (26, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(6 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(58 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 58)
, (27, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(7 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'V', CAST(29 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10019514', 29)
, (28, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(6 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(58 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'10018952', 58)
, (29, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'L', CAST(35 AS Decimal(18, 0)), NULL, 35)



INSERT [dbo].[Task_Header] ([Task_Sno], [Shipment_ID], [Vehicle_Id], [DepotVisitStartTime], [Time_V], [Time_T], [Time_C]) VALUES 
(1, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(2, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(3, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(4, CAST(1 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'TN1       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(5, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'KA2       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(6, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'KA2       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(7, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:32:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(8, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:32:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(9, CAST(3 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'AP3       ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T13:12:21.0000000' AS DateTime2), NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Expected Result with filter:

Sort Data by Shipment_ID , TASK_SEQUENCE_NUMBER
filter where Location_code  <> 'RJC'
Join of TaskMaster and TaskDetails is Shipment_id
TASK_TYPE should be V in a given sequence, next immediate with T , next immediate with C  only considered for output

Sample data : result in column V : 59 is sum of "V" value for the given Shipment_Id result data is group by shipment_id

[image: VTC Image for fliter and sort and group data]

**Expected Result**

```
Sno Shipment_ID Vehicle ID  DepotVisitStartTime V   T   C
1   1   TN1 2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
2   1   TN1 2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
3   1   TN1 2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
4   1   TN1 2019-02-15 07:25:33.0000000 59  38  21
5   2   KA2 2019-02-15 06:12:52.0000000 0   0   0
6   2   KA2 2019-02-15 06:12:52.0000000 0   0   0
7   3   AP3 2019-02-15 06:32:52.0000000 29  19  10
8   3   AP3 2019-02-15 06:32:52.0000000 29  19  10
9   3   AP3 2019-02-15 13:12:21.0000000 29  19  10
```

These columns are continuation of below post and i want to have an StoredProceudre to insert data into Task_Master table
[Aggregate Date and quantity in same table for given ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808180/aggregate-date-and-quantity-in-same-table-for-given-id/54808529?noredirect=1#comment96399340_54808529)

Comment: Please don't post data as as image; it isn't helpful to the volunteers you're asking help from. Post data as `text`. Also, please don't using the HTML snippet tool for SQL. SQL isn't HTML, so putting it in those boxes doesn't make it as easy to read as if you were to use the Code formatter instead; it's the `{}` button when you're writing your post. Thanks..

Comment: Nice job posting ddl and sample data. But I don't understand the output at all. The values you want in your output are not in your data. Where does 59 come from??? Also, I don't really understand your schema here or how these tables can be joined. The more I look at these two tables the more I don't get it.

Comment: @ Larnu, Noted 
@Sean Lange
Join between both the tables is Shipment_Id
59 is sum of "V" value for the given Shipment_Id
result data is group by shipment_id

Comment: @Raj . . . Why does your sample result set have duplicate rows?

Comment: The values shown in the sample is looking like duplicated since i have removed other columns which are not part of the issue. there are many coloumns in the final table in which i have used only few columns and the VTC column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code given by @Gordon seems to be mostly correct, just changing the column names in main logic, hope this helps!

```
select Shipment_ID,
       sum(case when task_type = 'V' then task_duration else 0 end) as v_duration,
       sum(case when task_type = 'T' then task_duration else 0 end) as t_duration,
       sum(case when task_type = 'C' then task_duration else 0 end) as c_duration
from (select td.*,
             lead(task_type) over (partition by Shipment_ID order by TASK_SEQUENCE_No) as next_task_type,
             lead(task_type, 2) over (partition by Shipment_ID order by TASK_SEQUENCE_No) as next2_task_type,
             lag(task_type) over (partition by Shipment_ID order by TASK_SEQUENCE_No) as prev_task_type,
             lag(task_type, 2) over (partition by Shipment_ID order by TASK_SEQUENCE_No) as prev2_type
      from task_detail td --WHERE Location_Code <>'RJC'
     ) td
where (task_type = 'V' and next_task_type = 'T' and next2_task_type = 'C') or
      (prev_task_type = 'V' and task_type = 'T' and next_task_type = 'C') or
      (prev2_type = 'V' and prev_task_type = 'T' and task_type = 'C')

group by Shipment_ID;
```

Adding the image of the result obtained.[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBddW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select ship_id,
       sum(case when task_type = 'V' then task_duration else 0 end) as v_duration,
       sum(case when task_type = 'T' then task_duration else 0 end) as t_duration,
       sum(case when task_type = 'C' then task_duration else 0 end) as c_duration
from (select td.*,
             lead(task_type) over (partition by ship_id order by task_sid) as next_task_type,
             lead(task_type, 2) over (partition by ship_id order by task_sid) as next2_task_type,
             lag(task_type) over (partition by ship_id order by task_sid) as prev_task_type,
             lag(task_type, 2) over (partition by ship_id order by task_sid) as prev2_type,
      from task_detail td
     ) td
where (task_type = 'V' and next_task_type = 'T' and next2_task_type = 'C') or
      (prev_task_type = 'V' and task_type = 'T' and next_task_type = 'C') or
      (prev2_task_type = 'V' and prev_task_type = 'T' and task_type = 'C')
group by ship_id;
```

Comment: i am getting value as 
shipment_id v_duration t_duration c_duration
3 0 19 10

Comment: not getting value as expected after fixing the issues of alais names